# How to use a storage class for StateFulSet? Do I have to create a PVC?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

How to use a storage class for statefulset?  I've created the StorageClass. I also created PVC but i'm a bit confused if PVC needs to be create since PVC already requests storage and volumeClaimTemplates also requests storage. Eitherway its not working with or with out pvc.

I get the following error:

```
create Pod dbhost001-0 in StatefulSet dbhost001 failed error: failed to create PVC mysql-dev-dbhost001-0: PersistentVolumeClaim "mysql-dev-dbhost001-0" is invalid: spec.resources[storage]: Required value
create Claim mysql-dev-dbhost001-0 for Pod dbhost001-0 in StatefulSet dbhost001 failed error: PersistentVolumeClaim "mysql-dev-dbhost001-0" is invalid: spec.resources[storage]: Required value
```

`storageClass.yml`:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: ebs-sc
provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
parameters:
  type: gp2
reclaimPolicy: Retain
allowVolumeExpansion: true
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

`Statefultset.yml`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
....
....
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: mysql-dev
    spec:
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
      storageClassName: ebs-sc
      resources:
        requests:
          stroage: 2Gi
```

I'm not sure if pvc is needed? I was using this for a normal replicaset deployment. But not sure if Statefulset needs this.

`PersistentVolumeClaim.yml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-dev
  namespace: test-db-dev
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: ebs-sc
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out.

First there was a typo in `Statefultset.yml` it should be `storage` instead of `stroage`.

Second there is no need for `PersistentVolumeClaim` since `volumeClaimTemplates` is the same thing which claims from storage class.

Comment: There is also no need for `StorageClass` since you can use the AWS default